# How do calculate coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordinates

I have a list coordinates same latitude, longitude. I want to divide them into a circle around the original coordinate.
For example I have a list of 6 items the same coordinates, how do i get list vertex point's coordinates of hexagon by use JavaScript with google map
[image: divided coordinates from list of 6 location same coordinate]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate 6 vertices of randomely generated hexagon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945593/calculate-6-vertices-of-randomely-generated-hexagon). I think the code here can be easily adopted to return the coordinates instead of plotting them.

Comment: Look like it was 2D. I want to do with map coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Ken Y-N's comment is exactly what you are looking for.

```
fucntion printPoints(latitude, longitude, radius, vertices){

    for (var i = 0; i < vertices; i ++){
        console.log([latitude + (radius*Math.cos(Math.PI*2/vertices * i)), longitude + (radius*Math.sin(Math.PI*2/vertices * i))]);
    }

}

printPoints(0, 0, 10, 6); //prints [10, 0] [5, 8.7] [-5, 8.7] [-10, 0] [-5, -8.7] [5, -8.7]
```

This function simply prints the coordinates, but you can modify it as you would like to.

Comment: Looking at your image, you might like to add 90 degree turn (+ Math.PI/2) to the angles you give to the trigonometric function. So that the vertex will start at the top instead of the right side.